# Manually rebuild a `.key` Keynote file from components

Tags: osx-mavericks, keynote

I've been recovering data from a busted hard drive and was forced to do a terminal `cp -R` with my Apple Keynote `.key` files because it viewed them as directories.  It broke them into components (including a `Data` folder with all the images, `Index.zip`, `Metadata` folder and some previews).

The drive is now officially dead so there's no going back but I need to turn these components into a functional `.key` presentation... How?

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the folder containing these files with the `.key` extension and you're good to go.  Face palm.